# How to uninstall older version of Xcode

Tags: xcode, uninstallation

I have Xcode 4.0.2 and 3.2.5 both installed on my macbook. How do I uninstall the older version without uninstalling the newer version?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

where `<Xcode>` is the path to the Developer folder (the one with 'Xcode 3.2.5' in it)
This won't affect the 'Xcode 4.0.2' installation since it's in a completely different folder.

Comment: Superb thanks so much. I have been wandering for a long time as to why I have two versions of Xcode installed on my Mac... Ever since Xcode came to the Mac App Store, I have had two versions installed. Now all these years later with Xcode 7.0, I think its time I got rid of Xcode 4.2 lol...

Answer (score 38):

- Your **XCode 4.x** is installed in your `/Applications/ folder`
- The old **XCode 3.x** is installed in `/Developer/` and can be independently uninstalled by running the following command :

> sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all

It is a nice mv from the XCode Apple Developers Team :)

Comment: I love that terminal command so much... it just works perfectly.

Comment: I am new to mac.  What is a typical path for <XCode>?

Comment: @RobinHsu I wanted to answer your question for any future person that looks at this. Xcode is typically located in the /Developer folder (/Your Hard Drive/Library/Developer) it can vary computer to computer though