# brew doctor says "Your Xcode (3.2) is outdated Please install Xcode 4.6.2." but I already have it installed

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew

```
brew doctor
```

gave me bunch of warnings, the last one is

```
Warning: Your Xcode (3.2) is outdated
Please install Xcode 4.6.2.
```

But I already have it installed on Mac OS X 10.8.3.

Comment: Might you have Xcode 3.2 installed on a backup drive or similar?

Comment: I've found ver 3.2 in Developer/Applications/

Comment: You are compiling with the older version. You can remove the older version of xcode then compile, or just locate the encode 4.6, open it and choose the project from the recent tab and recompile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To uninstall older Xcode I did:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041871/how-to-uninstall-older-version-of-xcode), and the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the Xcode-select utility to set the default Xcode path:

```
 sudo xcode-select -switch /path/to/Xcode.app
```

If this doesn't work you might also have to download and install the latest Xcode command line tools.