# How can i uninstall the old version Command Line Tools when i have new version xcode already

Tags: xcode, macos, command-line-tool

I have installed Xcode6.3 completely and after that I download CLT for Xocde6.2 for test from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode and I installed the old version CLT.

My question is how i can uninstall the old version CLT(for Xcode6.2) and keep my new version CLT(for Xcode6.3) ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possibly duplictae: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041871/how-to-uninstall-older-version-of-xcode

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the version of CLT you want to use, Please refer to this link : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-locations_preferences/SpecifyingCommandLineTools/SpecifyingCommandLineTools.html

Otherwise, since Xcode includes its own copy of the Command line tools (i.e. they are bundled as part of Xcode.app), you will have to uninstall Xcode (delete Xcode.app in Applications folder, then restart the mac)  in order to remove the CLT version you want to uninstall.